# C to Java port: calculating a 3 byte checksum

Tags: java, c, checksum

Does this seem correct? I'm trying to port this checksum method from C to Java but the values returned from my Java function are too high. I suspect the way I'm fudging the unsigned int is not correct?

```
char *Generate( char * buffer, long length ) {

     static char tBuf[4];
     long index;
     unsigned int checksum;

     for( index = 0L, checksum = 0; index < length; checksum += (unsigned int) buffer[index++] );
     sprintf( tBuf, "%03d", (unsigned int) ( checksum % 256 ) );
     return( tBuf );

}
```

My Java port:

```
public String generateCheckSum( String value ) {        

    char[] chars = value.toCharArray();        
    long checksum = 0L;

    for( int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++ ) {                 
        checksum += (checksum + (long) chars[ i ]) & 0xFF;
    }

    return String.valueOf( checksum % 256 );
}
```

Any insight is very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Just one note: A string in Java is *not* an array of bytes. It's an array of *chars* ... which are individual UTF-16 *code units*. If you want a checksum over an array of bytes, then use bytes, not chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++

```
checksum += (unsigned int) buffer[index++]
```

Java

```
checksum += (checksum + (long) chars[ i ]) & 0xFF
```

There's an extra checksum in there

Comment: Opps, that was a typo on my part in the question, my Java code is:

checksum = (checksum + (long) chars[ i ]) & 0xFF

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think in your Java code

```
checksum += (checksum + (long) chars[ i ]) & 0xFF;
```

should be

```
checksum += ((long) chars[ i ]) & 0xFF;
```

?

Also in your C function, you are using incorrect format specifier for `unsigned int`. It should  be `%u` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version

```
public String generateCheckSum(String value) {        
    int checksum = 0;
    for(char ch : value.toCharArray()) checksum += ch;
    return "" + (checksum & 0xFF);
}
```

Note: checksum % 256 and checksum & 0xFF don't do the same thing. The first is signed and can return a negative result, the second will not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the feedback, it allowed me to get to my final solution. I'm sure it could be tweaked further but it does produce the desired checksum values.

```
public Integer generateCheckSum(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    byte[] data = value.getBytes("US-ASCII");        
    long checksum = 0L;

    for( byte b : data )  {
        checksum += b; 
    }

    checksum = checksum % 256;

    return new Long( checksum ).intValue();

}
```